# Asp.net Core 3.1 Binding: Action with a Dictionary as parameter in GET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, action

We are defining an action that will be used to search documents stored in a repository; the interface allows to specify a list of filters to narrow down the result.

```
[Route("search")]
        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(List<DocumentDto>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        public async Task<ActionResult<DocumentDto>> GetDocuments(
        [FromServices] IDocumentManager documentManager,
        [FromQuery] Dictionary<string, string> filters)
        {
            //Do something
        }
```

We are using a parameter like `Dictionary<string, string> filters` in the action signature because we would like to implement a search using a GET method but with a dynamic list of parameters.
Filters are just a list of `key:value` objects which the action will pass to a Database, the only layer that knows how to handle them.
We consume the service calling an url like this:

```
  /search?filter1=value1&filter2=value2&filter3=value3
```

The binding seems to "work" and `filters` is populated with something like this:

```
filters
[0] {[filter1, value1]}
[1] {[filter2, value2]}
[2] {[filter3, value3]}
```

Checking the [binding chapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#dictionaries) related to Dictionaries, it seems that the parameters passed in query string like we are doing is not documented.

Are we seeing a binding side effect?
Is the syntax we are using to pass filters from query string to a dictionary supported?

Comment: this seems to be a bit problematic - binding should be about making things strongly typed and a dictionary you are asking for it to discard that.

Comment: @DanielA.White I agree but dictionary binding is supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit more or less problematic using binding like that. The dictionary on your controller is catching all the query parameters, such that if your query string is:

```
/search?filter1=value1&filter2=value2&filter3=value3&random=randomValue
```

You will see in the dictionary:

```
filters
[0] {[filter1, value1]}
[1] {[filter2, value2]}
[2] {[filter3, value3]}
[3] {[random, randomValue]}
```

When ASP.NET Core creates the context for model binding for a parameter, the model name [comes from one of the sources](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/ParameterBinder.cs#L157):

1. Explicit name (such as `[FromQuery(Name = ...)]`
2. From the value provider (in this case `QueryStringValueProvider`)

In your example, none of the above is true, so the model name in the binding context will be empty. This will cause the [DictionaryModelBinder](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/DictionaryModelBinder.cs#L162) to populate arbitrary parameters in the query string to the dictionary.

I'd recommend fixing your query string as per the documentation you referenced.